# AIR 3.0 and Stage3D

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

There isn't any tutorials on the web on how to use Stage3D on AIR 3.0. How do I enable it in Flash Builder 4?

I have countless trial and error when testing 2D/3D framework:

```
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flash.display::Stage3D could not be found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need the flex 4.5.1 SDK installed, as well as a playerglobal.swc from FP11.  Check out this tutorial: [Creating a Custom Flex 4.5 SDK to Target Flash 11 and AIR 3](http://blogs.cynergysystems.com/2011/09/20/creating-a-custom-flex-4-5-sdk-to-target-flash-11-and-air-3/)

Comment: Link is no longer a blog post.

Comment: This is moot, as Flex 4.6 SDK is now released, which targets Flash Player 11 and supports Stage3D.  No special instructions are needed, just download the SDK directly from Adobe: http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+4.6

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your app's XML file. That's the descriptor file with settings like the icons, resolutions etc. You need to add or edit:

`<renderMode>gpu</renderMode>`

This goes inside the `<initialWindow>` tag.

Comment: I done this long ago and tried any combination from the any tutorials, however, the error is not related to this since it need to be aware of the API in stage3D.